# How to retrieve integer value from url of "example_3.html"

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, data-retrieval

Title says it all. Basically I am looking to retrieve the end of the url using jQuery to add one to the selection and go to that page. I had some help from someone else on her but I want to understand how it is working/ why it's not working:

```
var urlFrags = window.location.href.replace(".html", "").split("_"),

curPage = parseInt(urlFrags[urlFrags.length]),

nextPage = "example_" + (curPage + 1) + ".html";
```

It could be an error somewhere else, but I am working down the line trying to bug-fix it.
I understand pretty much everything going on, except I don't understand parseInt() and stuff.

Would it be possible to '.getAsIntiger(urlFrags)' ? (I have tried this but I may have implemented wrong.)

Comment: `parseInt()` will turn a _String_ into an _Integer_. If for example you have the string "Text1"*, it will turn into _1_. With that _1_ you can perform mathematical equetions. _*it strips out all the text that cannot be turned into a number_. Parameters and more at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: If your format is same then you could also use replace method to get your desired output as below: `"example_" + (parseInt("example_3.html".replace("example_","").replace(".html","")) + 1) + ".html"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error there is here:

```
curPage = parseInt(urlFrags[urlFrags.length]);
```

You should be doing

```
curPage = parseInt(urlFrags[urlFrags.length-1]);
```

Since if you have a length of 2 in your array, you cannot access Array[2] because it doesn't exist. You have to access Array[1] because the array index starts in 0.

Comment: YOU SIR AND OR MADAM HAVE MADE MY WEEK!

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a `var num = parseInt(/.+?_(\d+)\.html/.exec(window.location.href)[1])`

Comment: Personally I find the OP's solution much easier on the eyes, and I can read Regex just fine. Additionally you are assuming only numbers 0-9 and not double/triple digits.